# Database won't connect, no results returned

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

So I've got three PHP files, and I'm trying to connect my database through these files. It won't seem to connect, I'm trying to connect it so then my ajax in my javascript file will hopefully work.

BaseClass.php:

```
<?php
    require("Conn.php");
    require("MySQLDao.php");

    $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $raw_post_data = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);

    if (empty($raw_post_data))
    {
        $returnValue["status"] = false;
        $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
        $returnValue["message"] = "No Data Recieved";
        echo json_encode($returnValue);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $dao = new MySQLDao();
        if ($dao->openConnection() == false)
        {
            $returnValue["status"] = false;
            $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
            $returnValue["message"] = "Connection Could Not Be Established Between Server And Database";
            echo json_encode($returnValue);
        }
        else
        {
            //Decodes data, dont change
            $body = json_decode($raw_post_data, true);
            $recieved = $body["data"];

            //Gets the result of a query
            //$result = $dao->MySQLDaoMethodName(parameters);

            //Return the result of the query
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
        $dao->closeConnection();
        return;
    }
?>
```

When I run this in chrome all it shows is:

{"status":false,"title":"Error","message":"No Data Recieved"}

MySQLDao.php:

```
<?php
    //Class for holding queries
    class MySQLDao
    {
        var $dbhost = null;
        var $dbuser = null;
        var $dbpass = null;
        var $mysqli = null;
        var $dbname = null;
        var $result = null;


        //constructor
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->dbhost = Conn::$dbhost;
            $this->dbuser = Conn::$dbuser;
            $this->dbpass = Conn::$dbpass;
            $this->dbname = Conn::$dbname;
        }

        //Attempt a connection to the database
        public function openConnection()
        {   

            //Try and connect to the database
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
            //If the connection threw an error, report it
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //Get method for retrieving the database conection
        public function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->mysqli;
        }

        //Close the connection to the database
        public function closeConnection()
        {
            //If there is a connection to the database then close it
            if ($this->mysqli != null)
                $this->mysqli->close();
        }

        //-----------------------------------QUERY METHODS-------------------------------------

        public function getResults($data)
        {

            $sql = "SELECT room.room_description FROM room WHERE room.room_id = 1";

            $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);


            //if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            //  $obj = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'obResults');

            //}

            echo json_encode($result);

            echo($result);

        }

    }
?>
```

Nothing shows when I run this in chrome. Even when I put echo statements in some of the functions.

Conn.php:

```
<?php
    class Conn
    {
        public static $dbhost = "***";
        public static $dbname = "***";
        public static $dbuser = "***";
        public static $dbpass = "";
    }
?>
```

part of my test.html:

```
function callPHP() {
    $.ajax ({

        type: "GET",
        datatype: "application/json",
        url: "MySQLDao.php",
        data: { action : 'getResults()' },
        //error: function(err){console.log(err)},
        success: function(output) {

            console.log(output);

        }
        //error, function(err){console.log(err)}
    });


}
```

I basically just want to be able to write query methods and transport the results from these querys to my js, this is because I have a few graphs in my javascript and I want to get data from the database. All this code doesn't produce any errors I believe but it's just not returning anything back.
All help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you watched the network console to see if it's returning a response at all, or returning an error 500?

Comment: The only one I'm getting a network console response from is the js file just about the ajax and the status is 200 okay apparently :(

Comment: Your AJAX is calling the wrong file. `MySQLDao.php` will just compile a class. You cannot make it call a method of the class by using `data: { action : 'getResults()' }`

Comment: I also dont see where anything uses `BaseClass.php` either. So not sure how you are getting that message back from that code

Comment: What shall I change the ajax to? Thanks

Comment: `BaseClass.php` is also badly named, as it is NOT a class and NOT a base class.

Comment: I would start by calling `url: "BaseClass.php",` but rename that code something more appropriate first

Comment: But doesnt the js need to call the MySQLDao.php file instead? Thats where I'm gonna put my queries

Comment: No! in `BaseClass.php` the line `$dao = new MySQLDao();` instantiates that class. Once that is done you call the relevant methods in that class

Comment: But I need this line to get the query result: $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);  and all the stuff for this is in the MySQLDao.php. What shall I do?

Comment: Ohh Okay I get you, I've called the baseClass but its still not connected.